# How to correctly pass a dependency from one target to the next?

Tags: cmake

After switching a target `cwd_r` from (in the project root's `CMakeLists.txt`)

```
pkg_check_modules(libcwd_r libcwd_r IMPORTED_TARGET GLOBAL)
```

to

```
find_package(libcwd_r CONFIG)
```

I am getting suddenly an error for previously working code (in `events/CMakeLists.txt`):

```
add_executable(test1 test1.cxx)
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE AICxx::events AICxx::utils AICxx::cwds)
```

this used to worked fine, and I'd like it to work again without that I have to
change the `events/CMakeLists.txt` that these two lines are a part of.

The error is:

```
CMake Error at events/CMakeLists.txt:59 (add_executable):
  Target "test1" links to target "Threads::Threads" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

The way that `Threads::Threads` gets dragged in here is because it is
a PUBLIC dependency of `AICxx::cwds`.

To narrow things down, lets first change the second line into

```
target_link_libraries(test1 PRIVATE AICxx::cwds)
```

simply leaving away the `AICxx::events AICxx::utils`. As expected this gives the exact same error, because linking doesn't happen yet.

The target `AICxx::cwds` is defined in `cwds/CMakeLists.txt` with

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
[...snip...]
add_library(cwds_ObjLib OBJECT)
[...snip...]
# Add dependencies.
target_link_libraries(cwds_ObjLib
  PUBLIC
    Boost::boost
    Threads::Threads
)

if (OptionEnableLibcwd)
  target_link_libraries(cwds_ObjLib
    PUBLIC
      ${libcwd_r_TARGET}
   )
endif ()

# Create an ALIAS target.
add_library(AICxx::cwds ALIAS cwds_ObjLib)
```

where `OptionEnableLibcwd` is true and `libcwd_r_TARGET` is set to the correct target name (`Libcwd::cwd_r`) of libcwd_r.

Note how `cwds` adds a dependency on `Threads::Threads` (and Boost). But since I only
changed how `libcwd_r` is found that can't be what gives the problem, right?

To test that hypothesis - I also removed the `Threads::Threads` from the `target_link_libraries` in this `cwds/CMakeLists.txt`, and indeed still the exact same error. Hence (as expected) it is complaining about something that it inherited from `Libcwd::cwd_r`.

My question is now: if the (found) target `Libcwd::cwd_r` specifies a dependency `Threads::Threads`, then why do I get this error? Shouldn't it be hidden from the final user (test1) who doesn't even know that `Threads::Threads` is being used (it just links with `AICxx::cwds`)? The answer to that *is* yes! Because before, when I was using `pkg_check_modules` it worked!

So what has changed? What is wrong? How can I fix this?
And most importantly, what does cmake expect with regard to passing down dependencies like this? The error seems to indicate that I have to add a `find_package(Threads)` everywhere?!

Comment: Are you sure this is the only thing that changed? Could you create a full [MCVE]? In what order and from where are `add_subdirectory` called?

Comment: I will have to do that if nobody can explain in general what is normal practise - but it will take me hours to make a minimal reproducible example. It would be a lot easier to just use the project as-is (it is open source and on the internet). And yes, I can change three lines to go back to pkg_check_modules and it works again. That is really the only change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate reason for the difference between the two is that `pkg_check_modules` isn't adding the target `Threads::Threads` (or any target) to the `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property of the returned target `PkgConfig::libcwd_r`. Specifically, the latter has the property

```
INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libcwd_r.so;/usr/lib/libdl.so
```

(slightly changed to make the paths shorter here). This being extracted from its `.pc` file:

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
datadir=${prefix}/share
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libcwd_r
Description: C++ Debugging Support Library for threaded applications
Version: 1.1.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lcwd_r -ldl
Cflags: -DCWDEBUG -DLIBCWD_THREAD_SAFE -I${includedir}
```

While the [cmake package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#config-file-packages) of libcwd *does* set this target. Namely it has the property,

```
INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES = Threads::Threads;dl
```

which is set in the installed `libcwd_rTargets.cmake` file (one of the four files of the cmake package):

```
set_target_properties(Libcwd::cwd_r PROPERTIES
  COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_STRING "cwd_r_MAJOR_VERSION"
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "CWDEBUG;LIBCWD_THREAD_SAFE;VERSION=\"1.1.2\""
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "Threads::Threads;dl"
  INTERFACE_cwd_r_MAJOR_VERSION "5"
)
```

With this "new" dependency, the error occurs because this dependency doesn't have a accompanied `find_package`.

Namely, an imported target like that has the scope of its (sub)directory and needs to have a `find_package` where it is being introduced, in the same scope. Aka, where ever you have `Threads::Threads` literally in your `CMakeLists.txt`, that `CMakeLists.txt` also needs to have a `find_package(Threads)`.

In this case however, the `Threads::Threads` is used in the `libcwd_rTargets.cmake` file. The correct way to add the `find_package` for dependencies like this is with [find_dependency](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html) by adding that to the package' `*Config.cmake` file:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)
find_dependency(Threads)
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libcwd_rTargets.cmake")
```

where the first two lines were missing; hence the error that I got. See for example the answer of cmake developer Matthew Woehlke at the end of this [thread](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18590).

Comment: Thanks a bunch to 'K-ballo' of IRC who pointed out that and where I should use `find_dependency`!